# Intent Service derived call explicit super class constructor

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I am learning android and came across an example like

```
public static class A extends IntentService {
    public A() {
        super("AppWidget$A");
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me why do we have to call constructor of the superclass(IntentService) explicitly? and what does the parameter string signify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is used only for debugging. Here is a part of IntentService source code that uses this:

```
public abstract class IntentService extends Service {

    ...
    private String mName;
    ...

    /**
     * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
     *
     * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
     */
    public IntentService(String name) {
        super();
        mName = name;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("IntentService[" + mName + "]");
        thread.start();

        mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
        mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain the onCreate code a bit and Is it necessary to pass the parameter in the form <calling class>$<working class> or is it just a convention?

Comment: @deXter: I'll give explanation only in regard to `mName` usage. As you see it is used to create a name to the handler thread (there is a Thread constructor that accepts a name). This is only useful when you need to log what thread is running now. So somewhere internally Android uses this for a human friendly logging. Basically what happens here is a preparation to execute the IntentService payload on a non-UI background thread.

Comment: @deXter: regarding the `<calling class>$<working class>` - I believe this is smth what the code writer decided to use as his/her own pattern. In this case I usually simply pass the name of my IntentService class.

Answer (score 0):

IntentService has a single constructor that takes a string argument 
"name".I found that its only use is in naming the worker thread for the IntentService. This thread is named IntentService [name].